# Sending Email with Python using Outlook desktop application - clipboard as the input for email address

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to send the following email automated with Python but i keep get an error. I would like to run the script and then for it to ask me for input on which email address to send it to. But I keep getting an error. If I put an actual email address in the Msg.To section it works but I was hoping that every time I run this script it would ask me which email address to send to (originally I was trying to have it simply use whats on my clipboard as the input but that seemed too complicated so I relegated to input prompt instead).

Here is my code:

```
emailrecepient = input("enter email address")


import win32com.client

o = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")

Msg = o.CreateItem(0)
Msg.Importance = 2
Msg.Subject = 'SUBJECT'
Msg.HTMLBody = """<p>Hello,<br>"""

Msg.To = "sender"


Msg.Send()
```

Comment: solved leaving it up in case anyone else wants to see this

Comment: You may wanna answer your own post, as someone might glance over it considering there's no answer on this post. It might come off as an unanswered question.